# Create a foreign key field not mapped with a field in database in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

How can I create a foreign key field with a field in the database in Entity Framework?

I want create a relation between `DecodePersonnelID` in table `MyUser` and `PersonnelID` in table `Personnel` (field key).

```
public partial class MyUser
{
    public int UsersID { get; set; }
    public string PersonnelID { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int DecodePersonnelID
    {
        get { return DecodeMD5PersonnelID(PersonnelID); }
        set { PersonnelID = EncodeMD5(value.ToString() ); }
    }
    public string UsersName { get; set; }
}

public partial class Personnel
{
    public int PersonnelID { get; set; }
    public string FirstNameFa { get; set; }
    public string LastNameFa { get; set; }
    public bool Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what kind of relationship is this?

Answer (score 0):

If `DecodePersonnelID` is the column in table `MyUser` you must do it the other way around, i.e. mark `PersonnelID` with `[NotMapped]`, and then mark `DecodePersonnelID` as foreign key:

```
public partial class MyUser
{
    public int UsersID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string PersonnelID
    {
        get { return EncodeMD5(DecodePersonnelID.ToString()); }
        set { DecodePersonnelID = DecodeMD5PersonnelID(value); }
    }

    [ForeignKey("Personnel")]
    public int DecodePersonnelID { get; set; }
    public string UsersName { get; set; }

    public Personnel Personnel { get; set; }
}

public partial class Personnel
{
    public int PersonnelID { get; set; }
    public string FirstNameFa { get; set; }
    public string LastNameFa { get; set; }
    public bool Gender { get; set; }
}
```

This will create a one-to-many relationship between `MyUser` and `Personnel` with `MyUser.Personnel` as navigation and `DecodePersonnelID` as foreign key property.

Answer (score 0):

you can define `public virtual Personnel Personnel { get; set; }` in your `MyUser` :

```
public partial class MyUser
{
    public int UsersID { get; set; }

    public string PersonnelID { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int DecodePersonnelID
    {
        get { return DecodeMD5PersonnelID(PersonnelID); }
        set { PersonnelID = EncodeMD5(value.ToString() ); }
    }
    public string UsersName { get; set; }
    public virtual Personnel Personnel { get; set; }
}
public partial class Personnel
{
    public int PersonnelID { get; set; }
    public string FirstNameFa { get; set; }
    public string LastNameFa { get; set; }
    public bool Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Slauma posted the same answer 2 days ago, check below.

Comment: I want create relation between two field public int PersonnelID and public int DecodePersonnelID but The database does not exist DecodePersonnelID